# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter - populateViewHolder not accessing data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebaseui

I am trying to display some data from my real time DB into a recycler adapter with no luck. I have made the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter work on another activity(java) but on this one it just does not work(kotlin). The strange thing is that if I use a ValueEventListener the data return just fine, but the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter do not work.

CLASS:

```
class FriendsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var friendsDb: DatabaseReference

    private var currentUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friends)
        supportActionBar?.title = "Friends"

        friends_main_rec.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        friends_main_rec.setHasFixedSize(true)


        currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        friendsDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("FRIENDS")
                .child(currentUser!!.uid)

        val friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(
                Friends::class.java,
                R.layout.friend_single,
                FriendsViewHolder::class.java,
                friendsDb) {

            override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: FriendsViewHolder, model: Friends, position: Int) {
                Log.d("FriendsList", model.toString())
                viewHolder.setDate(model.date)
            }

        }

        friends_main_rec.adapter = friendsRecyclerViewAdapter
    }


    class FriendsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun setDate(date: String) {
            itemView.friend_single_date.text = date
            Log.d("FriendsList", date)
        }

    }
```

POJO:

```
data class Friends(var date: String)
```

[image]

The code seems fine to me, but obviously it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some problem in this line

```
friendsDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("FRIENDS")
                .child(currentUser!!.uid)
```

Here it will get value from **"FRIENDS/currentUser.uid"**, 
which is either of

- NBHxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxON2
- it3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfj1

You **can not directly access** `date` object from here, as **date is under freind user id**

Comment: I tried this friendsDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("FRIENDS")
                .child(currentUser!!.uid).child("it3jrOcDw1aNQe2vTWtJPeASpfj1") but is also not works.

Comment: Are you sure currentUser!!.uid is "NBHxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxON2" ?